# Issue setting Jenkins cron

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that runs every 15 minutes using the build periodically plugin .

```
H/15 * * * *
```

I want my cron to run 24X7 every 15 minutes except between 7pm to 10 pm

I tried the below:

```
H/15 H(22-19) * * *
```

But i get the below error when i apply save the changes:

```
A problem occurred while processing the request.
Logging ID=610f57aa-4455-46e4-9af6-3d5b71e6adf1
```

If I change this to

```
H/15 H(19-22) * * *
```

Then it works but instead of skipping 7pm to 10 pm it works during that time.

Comment: Don't really know anything about this, but my guess is that you can't have a range that's from bigger number to smaller number.

Comment: Seems it's an underlying [cron constraint](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) :Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a hyphen.  The specified range is inclusive. The first number must be less than or equal to the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at this [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18313) that looks very similar and is not resolved unfortunately.
I would suggest to change your cron to:

```
H/15 0-19,23 * * *
```

You can test your expression [here](http://cron.schlitt.info/) and [here](https://crontab.guru/) (but you have to replace H with 0 when testing).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to choose a timezone for the job where that window falls in the same day. [Cloudbees explains](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003237887-Scheduled-job-builds-are-not-triggering-on-time), eg: if in PST zone,

```
TZ=EST
H/15 H(0-3) * * *
```